# Проблема с обновлением приложения

Tags: c#, windows, cmd

Писал автообновляемое приложение на C#, проблема возникла в запуске уже обновленного приложения.

Если запустить update вручную то все отлично работает, но если все происходит автоматически, то запуск процесса не происходит, будто команда на запуск просто игнорируется.

Работает это все так:

1. Основному приложению приходит команда на обновление;
2. Основное приложение запускает процесс update.exe (или update.bat) и закрывается;
3. update скачивает новую версию и заменяет прошлую версию;
4. update запускает обновленную программу (тут проблема).

win10 (права админа), winXP (обычный юзер), все делается в корне appdata

P.S. Пробовал вариант с созданием батника, результат аналогичен, только при ручном запуске работает, использую System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()

Comment: А вы можете запустить этот файл вручную после загрузки?

Comment: Вы уверены, что при автоматическом запуске выдаете команду на запуск после завершения скачивания?

Comment: Вам случайно не показывается диалоговое окно «этот файл был загружен из интернета и может быть опасен»?

Comment: как именно качаете файл?

Comment: да, могу, все работает, нечего не выскакивает, с этим проблем нет, скачивает все через ftp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте указать в [ProcessStartInfo.Verb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.verb(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
startInfo.Verb = "runas";
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно, теперь все работает